# How do I change the RAILS_ENV for rspec integration or remote specs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I would like to create a set of remote specs "specs/remote" that run with the RAILS_ENV = 'remote'.  These specs need to use a different database than the model specs.  I would make them integration specs if that was easiest.

Ultimately, what is the easiest way change the RAILS_ENV from test and run a group of specs?

Answer (score 1):

- Create `remote.rb` in
  `config/environments`
- Tell rspec to use your custom
  environment by setting `export
  RAILS_ENV=remote` at the shell
  prompt.
- Add the `remote` environment to your
  `config/database.yml` with the
  appropriate settings for your
  alternate database.

Don't forget you can use YAML to include one environments configuration within another:

```
base: &base
  adapter: mysql

development:
  database: dev_database
  <<: *base

test:
  database: test_databae
  <<: *base

remote:
  database: remote_databae
  <<: *test
```

etc.